# How to send an email once the user press sequence of numbers

Tags: android, email, sequence

I'm new in android world..

I want in my application to send an email once the user enter some sequence of numbers.. For example, if the user enter "*1234" and other numbers then he presses a button. After that directly the number will be sent using an email address

Comment: is the user using the keyboard to input these numbers or some custom on-screen button interface?

Comment: On my app., I will make buttons which are numbers from 0 to 9 .. so when he press for example some sequence .. then it will be sent by email once the user press a button

Comment: So what is the difficulty?  Either use a textual input field, or build a state machine to track button presses. Using an intent to launch an existing email client with pre-filled content will be easiest though the user will have to send manually, otherwise you will need (library?) functionality to talk directly to their mail server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mind the haters on StackOverflow...here's a super simple way to do it...use the `android:onClick` attribute for all of your buttons so they'd each look something like this in the layout XML (except with different tag/text):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="checkSequence"
    android:tag="0"
    android:text="0"/>
```

Then define this method and these fields in your `Activity`:

```
private final String FIRST_DIGIT = "*";
private final String SECOND_DIGIT = "1";
private final String THIRD_DIGIT = "2";
private final String FOURTH_DIGIT = "3";
private int counter = 0;

public void checkSequence(View button){

    String input = button.getTag().toString();

    switch (counter){
        case 0:
            if (input.equals(FIRST_DIGIT)){
                counter++;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (input.equals(SECOND_DIGIT)){
                counter++;
            }else{
                //reset the counter b/c they've screwed up the sequence
                counter = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (input.equals(THIRD_DIGIT)){
                counter++;
            }else{
                counter = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (input.equals(FOURTH_DIGIT)){
                //here you know that they've finished the sequence, so send the email
                sendEmail();
                counter = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And then search StackOverflow/google for how to send an email using an `Intent`, and you'll be able to write the `sendEmail()` method.

Comment: Could you please write a simple example when I want to use the (*) at the beginning of the sequence because it doesn't work with me when I use the star .. Really Thanks for ur helping ..

Comment: This is my try : private final String first_DIGIT_id = "button_star";
 private final String Second_DIGIT_id = "button1";
 private final String third_DIGIT_id = "button3";

Comment: private int counter = 0;

 
 public void checkSequence(View button){

 
     
     String input_id = String.valueOf((button.getId()));


     switch (counter){
         case 0:
             if (input_id == first_DIGIT_id){
                 counter++;
             }
             break;

Comment: case 1:
             if (input_id == Second_DIGIT_id){
                 counter++;
             }else{
                 //reset the counter b/c they've screwed up the sequence
                 counter = 0;
             }
             break;

Comment: case 2:
             if (input_id == third_DIGIT_id){               
             }else{
                 counter = 0;
             }
             break;
         
           
     }

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneTextArea"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="checkSequence"
        android:tag="*"
        android:text="*" />

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonCall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_star"
        android:onClick="checkSequence"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="1" />

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"

Comment: android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:onClick="checkSequence"
        android:tag="3"
    />

Comment: I've changed my answer, pls accept it if it works for you!

Comment: It works with my now .. Thanks a lot for ur helping ..

Comment: I have a small question, the code worked, but when i put system.out.println("worked");
i get one time the string worked in the logcat
and if i press again *123
it skips the string

Comment: i've edited case 3 to reset the counter...c'mon you could've figure that one out.